# Fragment does not inflate upon item click in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

So I am building a standard Android Application with Kotlin. My app implements a TabLayout with one tab holding a RecyclerView List.

Now, this seems simple and I am not sure why it is not working. When I click on one of the items in my list, the listener is responsive (as I have made a few Log test), but the fragment associated to the item does not inflate!

In the OnCreateView() of my Fragment list where I implement my RecyclerView, I instruct the listener in this way:

```
    //Give action to item click in adapter
    adapter.onItemClick = { 

        //Setup new fragment Item
        val newFragment = ItemFragment()

        // parentFragmentManager is the same as activity?.supportFragmentManager
        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.list_fragment_id, newFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null) //Makes it possible to comeback to recyclerview
            .commit()
    }
```

I am thinking my mistake lies somewhere around the ID of the current container as the application is setup in TabLayout. I have tried to use the ID of my view pager or even the RecyclerView, but nothing seems to be successful.

Any help would be extremely helpful!

Comment: add onclick listener in your recycler view adapter's onBindViewHolder using holder.your_text_view.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

**Try to below code which has in java convert it to kotlin by your self :)**

First Declare var in your adapter

```
Fragment fragment = null;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
```

After Add below code in your onclick method

```
fragment = new CategoryFragment();
fragmentManager = ((FragmentActivity)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutHome, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply :)

Unfortunately it did not work. Your fragment manager is the same as mine and I added the setTransition but I am still without success... I think the key is really in the replace function of the fragment transaction. I feel like I am not using the right ID for to be replaced. As I am not 100% sure if the current container is my view pager from my tablayout or my recylcerview or even my fragment associated to the recyclerview (and hence the specific tab)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `adapter.onItemClick = ...`

You should put click listener on ViewHolder view

**Adaper class**

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent:ViewGroup, viewType:Int):MyViewHolder{
{
  return MyViewHolder(view, myClickListener)
}
```

**ViewHolder class**

```
class MyViewHolder : ViewHolder(v:View, myClickListener:ClickListener?) {
   itemView.onClick = { myClickListener?.clicked() };
}
```

Comment: Its already cared for. I can expand on it as this was the clearest way I proceeded: 
I added an attribute var onItemClick: ((Oeuvre) -> Unit)? = null to my adapter class and in my ViewHolder inner class (to the adapter class) I added an init of the form:         //action happens
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                onItemClick?.invoke(itemList[adapterPosition])
            }
        }
This part works amazing for me and I have no doubt that this is not the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found an answer by myself :')

It does indeed lie in the container of your view.

`.replace(R.id.list_fragment_id, newFragment)` does not work because you cannot replace a fragment with a layout, it needs to be done with VIEW

`.replace(R.id.viewPager, newFragment)` does not work because because viewPager is the view representing all your fragments viewing and not just the one you are looking for

`.replace(R.id.recyclerview, newFragment)` cannot hold another fragment

THUS I have nested my recyclerview in my XML file inside a RelativeLayout who represents the actual CONTAINER that we wish to replace the fragment with!

It should look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I have made a mistake, please let me know!